# How to return records in correct order in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, locale, collation

Query

```
select 'T' union all select 'Z'  order by 1
```

returns

```
Z
T
```

but correct order should be

```
T
Z
```

Tried in 3 different OSes

- Windows 2003 server "PostgreSQL 9.1.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit"
- Windows 7 "PostgreSQL 9.2.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit"
- Debian "PostgreSQL 9.1.2 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 64-bit"

Database settings are:

```
Collation:      et_EE.UTF-8 
Character type: et_EE.UTF-8
```

How to fix this?

**Update**

Databases were created using

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH TEMPLATE=template0 OWNER=mydb_owner ENCODING='UNICODE'
```

OS locale was Estonian in all cases so database was created in estonian locale.

```
select 'Z' collate "et_EE" union all select 'S' collate "et_EE" order by 1
```

returns correct order:

```
S
Z
```

but

```
select 'Z' collate "et_EE" union all select 'T' collate "et_EE" order by 1
```

as stated in answer returns invalid order:

```
Z
T
```

Comment: except that this order is valid according to Estonian collation rules - Z must come before T

Comment: Also: PostgreSQL 9.1.3? I quote the project page: *`We always recommend that all users run the latest available minor release for whatever major version is in use.`* That would be 9.1.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with original SQL.

Reason why it does not seem to work the way you expect it to because you use Estonian locale, but [Estonian collation rules](http://developer.mimer.com/charts/estonian.htm) require that 'Z' comes before 'T'.

You can either use different collation or create database in en_US.UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Thank you. Tried but it still returns invalid order: Z, T

Comment: It works for me for en_US.UTF-8. Unfortunately, SQLFiddle does not like this, so I cannot show it in SQLFiddle

Comment: Can you try estonian locale (et_EE.UTF-8). You can create databse in this locale. In real table Z letter is sorted before T for unknown reason

Comment: `select 'T' union all select 'A'  order by 1` returns correct result. So I think order by affects to the whole query result

Comment: The `order by` applies to the result of the union. @Andrus problem is a different one. His example works for me.

Comment: Can you tell how did you create database with Estonian locale in first place? Locale 'et_EE.UTF-8' does not seem exist on Postgres 9.2 for Windows. I think it will work on Linux, but I don't have access to Linux box with postgres right now

Comment: @mvp: databases were created using `CREATE DATABASE mydb WITH TEMPLATE=template0 OWNER=mydb_owner ENCODING='UNICODE'` I updated queston add added additional information

Answer (score 2):

**Nothing** is wrong with the query.

A `UNION [ALL]` (or `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT`) query is considered *one* query. `ORDER BY` applies to the union of all legs, not just the last one. You would have to use parenthesis to make the `ORDER BY` local to one leg of the query. Quoting the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION):

> **`select_statement`** `UNION [ ALL | DISTINCT ]` **`select_statement`**
>
> **`select_statement`** is any `SELECT` statement without an `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`,
>   `FOR UPDATE`, or `FOR SHARE` clause. (`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can be attached
>   to a subexpression if it is enclosed in parentheses. Without
>   parentheses, these clauses will be taken to apply to the result of the
>   `UNION`, not to its right-hand input expression.)

This just works (`a` sorts before `b`):

```
SELECT 'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'a'
ORDER BY 1
```

As does the original query in the question:

```
SELECT 'T' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Z'
ORDER BY 1
```

To check on your collation:

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

`et_EE.UTF-8` is the Estonian locale and `Z` comes before `T` in the [Estonian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estonian_alphabet). That's all.

**Nothing** is wrong with the collation.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the collation:

```
select 'T' collate "et_EE.utf8" a union all select 'Z' collate "et_EE.utf8" order by 1;
 a 
---
 Z
 T
```

While with the `en_US` collation it works:

```
select 'T' collate "en_US.utf8" a union all select 'Z' collate "en_US.utf8" order by 1;
 a 
---
 T
 Z
```