# Is order preserved after UNION in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, union

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_trail (
      old_email TEXT NOT NULL,
      new_email TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO audit_trail(old_email, new_email)
  VALUES ('harold_gim@yahoo.com', 'hgimenez@hotmail.com'),
         ('hgimenez@hotmail.com', 'harold.gimenez@gmail.com'),
         ('harold.gimenez@gmail.com', 'harold@heroku.com'),
         ('foo@bar.com', 'bar@baz.com'),
         ('bar@baz.com', 'barbaz@gmail.com');


WITH RECURSIVE all_emails AS (
  SELECT  old_email, new_email
    FROM audit_trail
    WHERE old_email = 'harold_gim@yahoo.com'
  UNION
  SELECT at.old_email, at.new_email
    FROM audit_trail at
    JOIN all_emails a
      ON (at.old_email = a.new_email)
)
SELECT * FROM all_emails;

        old_email         |        new_email
--------------------------+--------------------------
 harold_gim@yahoo.com     | hgimenez@hotmail.com
 hgimenez@hotmail.com     | harold.gimenez@gmail.com
 harold.gimenez@gmail.com | harold@heroku.com
(3 rows)

select old_email, new_email into iter1
from audit_trail where old_email = 'harold_gim@yahoo.com';
select * from iter1;
--       old_email       |      new_email
-- ----------------------+----------------------
--  harold_gim@yahoo.com | hgimenez@hotmail.com
-- (1 row)

select a.old_email, a.new_email into iter2
from audit_trail a join iter1 b on (a.old_email = b.new_email);
select * from iter2;
--       old_email       |        new_email
-- ----------------------+--------------------------
--  hgimenez@hotmail.com | harold.gimenez@gmail.com
-- (1 row)

select * from iter1 union select * from iter2;
--       old_email       |        new_email
-- ----------------------+--------------------------
--  hgimenez@hotmail.com | harold.gimenez@gmail.com
--  harold_gim@yahoo.com | hgimenez@hotmail.com
-- (2 rows)
```

As you can see the recursive code gives the result in right order, but the non-recursive code does not.
They both use `union`, why the difference?

Comment: There is no `ORDER BY` anywhere, so no. Even a bare `SELECT * FROM table` is not guaranteed to be ordered unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: In this case how would `order by` be useful? You basically want to preserve the order in which the table "grows".

Comment: @qed there is no order in which a "table grows". The data is not guaranteed to have any particular order in data pages. Which means the newer tuples are not guaranteed to always follow the older ones

Comment: ok, but there must be a way to simulate the record of growth, right?

Comment: Yep, create a sequence and put it in every new row (if you don't have it)

Comment: Add an `id serial PRIMARY KEY` column to your table (which has other benefits) and use `ORDER BY id`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically, your query is incorrect to begin with. Use **`UNION ALL`**, not <strike>`UNION`</strike> or you would incorrectly remove duplicate entries. (There is nothing to say the trail cannot switch back and forth between the same emails.) And `UNION` is highly likely to reorder rows.

The Postgres implementation for `UNION ALL` typically returns values in the sequence as appended - as long as you do *not* add `ORDER BY` at the end or do anything else with the result. But there is no formal guarantee, and since the advent of `Parallel Append` plans in Postgres 11, this can actually break. See this related post:

- [Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/316818/3684)

Be aware though, that each `SELECT` returns rows in arbitrary order unless `ORDER BY` is appended. There is no natural order in tables.

So this usually works:

```
SELECT * FROM iter1
UNION ALL  -- union all!
SELECT * FROM iter2;
```

To get a **reliable sort order**, and "simulate the record of growth", you can track levels like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_emails AS (
   SELECT  *, 1 AS lvl
   FROM    audit_trail
   WHERE   old_email = 'harold_gim@yahoo.com'

   UNION ALL  -- union all!
   SELECT t.*, a.lvl + 1
   FROM   all_emails  a
   JOIN   audit_trail t ON t.old_email = a.new_email
)
TABLE  all_emails
ORDER  BY lvl;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62489a68ce1e98f7bd8a309dd33158a1)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dbd06/4)</sub>

Aside: if `old_email` is not defined `UNIQUE` in some way, you can get multiple trails. You would need a unique column (or combination of columns) to keep it unambiguous. If all else fails you can (ab-)use the internal tuple ID `ctid` for the purpose of telling trails apart. But you should rather use your own columns. (Added example in the fiddle.)

- [In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500013/in-order-sequence-generation/17503095#17503095)

Consider:

- [How to return records in correct order in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895225/how-to-return-records-in-correct-order-in-postgresql/13897203#13897203)

Comment: Do you have a citation for Postgres guaranteeing preserving order with union all?    The docs don't seem to guarantee it and I need to know if I can rely on it..

Comment: @rrauenza: I don't know of any official guarantee. It's an implementation detail. That's why I formulated: *"implementation for `UNION ALL` is guaranteed ..."*. I removed the "guarantee" now to better reflect that. (But I am pretty sure it's not going to change.)

Comment: i would prefer to follow the standard and not coincidences (and today's implementation details - which could easily change tomorrow), and use explicit `ORDER BY` for the result. Also, another answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/316835/72776

Answer (score 5):

Ordering is never preserved after any operation in any reasonable database.  If you want the result set in a particular order, use `ORDER BY`.  Period.

This is *especially* true after a `UNION`.  `UNION` removes duplicates and that operation is going to change the ordering of the rows, in all likelihood.

Comment: Thanks for the dose of common sense. I think I'll just add an indicator column for my problem in order to force rows from the first table to be included (after a `limit ` op)

Answer (score -1):

Order is preserved if one can pass after all unions statement as below:

```
select "ClassName","SectionName","Students","OrderNo" from table
UNION 
select '----TOTAL----' as "ClassName",'----' as "SectionName",sum("Total Students"),9999 as "OrderNo" from table
ORDER BY "OrderNo"
```